# Which is better for storing private key in .NET - Windows application secure registry or encrypted configuration?

Tags: encryption, windows, key-management, .net

We are building an integration with a third party. We have decided to share a private key with the 3rd party app. What will be the best strategy to allow access for the key? Should the key be saved in some secure registry or should it be embedded in an encrypted configuration?